# How do I create a MVC Razor template for DisplayFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a couple of properties in my view model that are display-only but I need to retrieve their values using jQuery to perform a calculation on the page. The standard *Html.DisplayFor()* method just writes their value to the page. I want to create a razor template that will allow me to render each element as:

```
<span id="ElementsId">Element's value</span>
```

I know I can specify a template in *Html.DisplayFor()* to use a particular template for rendering the property but within that template how do I identify the *id* attribute to write into the *span* tag?

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Element, "MyTemplate");
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

OK, I found it and it's actually very simple. In my *Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates* folder I have *Reading.cshtml* containing the following:

```
@model System.Int32
<span id="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName">@Model</span>
```

This renders the correct tag using the name of the property as the *id* attribute and the value of the property as the contents:

```
<span id="Reading">1234</span>
```

In the view file this can be called using the following:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Reading, "Reading")
```

Or if the model property is decorated with *UIHint("Reading")* then the template name can be left out of the call to *DisplayFor()* and it will still render using the template:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Reading)
```

This should work equally well with custom editor templates.

Comment: So how do you handle `System.Int32?` (Nullable int). You can't make another view named `Int32?.cshtml`

Comment: The view is called Reading.cshtml, not Int32.cshtml. So if you have an `Int32?` property, you would create a new file `WhateverPropertyIsCalled.cshtml`, with `@model System.Int32?`. Disclaimer: I don't recall having this requirement myself and I haven't tested that this works.

Comment: I actually tested this out and if you create a file named `Int32.cshtml` with a model of `System.Int32?` you will override the default template and it will be picked up by both versions of int32 (nullable and not nullable).

Comment: Depending on how you are outputting the value inside the template, it might be a good idea to check for null and provide a default formatting when this occurs. I just did this on a similar template for currency values. When the user first gets your form, the value will be null (nothing entered yet.)

Comment: I am using a configurable template, so I feel the foreach loop can only be  used in my case, as the partial views are not available to the end users convenience.

Answer (score 12):

I read many SO posts about defining template for `@Html.DisplayFor` for Boolean property but I couldn't clearly understand them. Your question is closed to this and after grasping it, I decided to add a new answer including all steps needed for implementing that. It might be helpful for other people.

**1. Creating a template**

At first, you need to add a `Partial View` in path below (the path is very important):

```
Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/
```

For example, I created a `Partial View` that named `_ElementTemplate` and Fill it like this:

```
<span>
    @(@Model ? "Yes" : "No")
</span>
```

**2. Adding [UIHint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) to the Model**

To make a connection between your `property` and `template`, you should add `UIHint` attribute like below in your model class:

```
[UIHint("_YesOrNoTemplate")]
public bool MyProperty { get; set; }
```

**3. Using @Html.DisplayNameFor in View**

In every view that you need this property, you can use code below:

```
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MyProperty)
</div>
```

**Output**

The code above is rendered to code below in my example (`if (MyProperty == true)`):

```
<div>
    <span>
        Yes
    </span>
</div>
```

**Setting attributes**

For setting `id` or other html attributes you can use [ModelMetadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelmetadata?view=aspnetcore-2.1) like this:

```
<span id="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName">
    @(@Model ? "Yes" : "No")
</span>
```

**Output with attribute**

```
<div id="MyProperty">
    <span>
        Yes
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you may be missing the point of the question - I was specifically interested in how to render the element id

Comment: @DavidClarke You are right. I forgot it. I added `id` attribute.

Comment: This answer is better written than most full-blown articles :-)

Answer (score 7):

You could make this `id` part of the view model and use it in the display template:

```
<span id="@Model.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Value)</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's [an article](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html) explaining the `Templates` (Display + Editor) in Razor, and also the `UIHint` attribute.

Comment: Great article on using templates.  Worked like a champ for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue as the original post.

Not sure the last comment is valid. It would make the HTML id attribute a run-time value and therefore cannot be referenced with a design time name.

I used the overload of DisplayFor which allows you to add new objects onto the data dictionary (ViewBag)

My model is a C# object called Project with various properties. In my view I have this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectName, "StringDisplaySetHtmlID", new { HtmlID = "project-name" })
```

This is using a custom template called StringDisplaySetHtmlID and the last parameter adds a key value pair to the Viewbag.

My template file looks like this:

```
@model string
<span class = "display-field" id = "@(ViewBag.HtmlID)">@Model</span>
```

I'm also setting a class here for styling purposes. I've used the key name HtmlID rather than just ID to avoid a potential common naming collision.

Now in my javascript I can pick up the span's content using the following jquery:

```
var projectName = $('#project-name').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to build a display template that will output the following:

```
<span id="ElementsId">Element's value</span>
```

Would be this:

```
<span id="@Html.IdForModel()">@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m)</span>
```

These helpers may not have existed when this question was first posted, but this builds on David's answer in two ways:

1. Using `@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m)` instead of `@Model` will still utilize data annotations while rendering the value instead of just essentially running `ToString()` on it.
2. Using `@Html.IdForModel()` instead of `@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName` would be preferable in cases where the model is nested or repeated, and the ID is not going to simply be the property name.