# How to make Html.DisplayFor display line breaks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Embarrassingly newbie question:

I have a `string` field in my model that contains line breaks.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MultiLineText)
```

does not display the line breaks.

Obviously I could do some fiddling in the model and create another field that replaces `\n` with `<br/>`, but that seems kludgy.  What's the textbook way to make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace line break characters with <br /> in ASP.NET MVC Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220381/replace-line-break-characters-with-br-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

A HtmlHelper extension method to display string values with line breaks:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayWithBreaksFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    var model = html.Encode(metadata.Model).Replace("\r\n", "<br />\r\n");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(model);
}
```

And then you can use the following syntax:

```
@Html.DisplayWithBreaksFor(m => m.MultiLineField)
```

Comment: Where can I define it in MVC 4 ?

Comment: Good, but instead of returning `MvcHtmlString.Empty` when the value is null or empty I would invoke the standard `HtmlHelper.DisplayFor` method so that any NullDisplayText decoration can be used.

Comment: For other newbs who might not know, define cwills' DisplayWithBreaksFor() method inside "public static class HtmlExtensions { <put the method here> }"

Comment: Using a `DisplayTemplate` instead of introducing a `HtmlHelper`-method has the advantage, that it trickles down to properties and views that are not explicitly defined (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59249806)).

Answer (score 63):

i recommend formatting the output with css instead of using cpu consuming server side strings manipulation like .replace,

just add this style property to render multiline texts :

```
.multiline
{
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

then

```
<div class="multiline">
  my
  multiline
  text
</div>
```

**newlines** will render like **br** elements, test it here https://refork.codicode.com/xaf4

Comment: To improve on this so that `Html.DisplayFor` can still be used apply the `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.MultilineText)]` attribute to the `MultiLineText` property on the model and create a DisplayTemplate with the contents `@model string
<span class="multiline">@Model</span>`

Comment: It probably doesn't matter any more, but this doesn't work on IE9 and below

Answer (score 48):

In your view, you can try something like

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.MultiLineText).Replace("\n", "<br />"))
```

Comment: should be at least `.Replace("\r\n", ...)`. Also, the [solution from cwills](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10290684/1343917) below is much better, in my opinion.

Comment: No \n is really enough : remaining \r will not harm since they are juste whitespace for html. While matching on \r\n will miss unix style newline and will not handle them.

Comment: Not sure if it was because I'm using `ViewData` instead of a regular property, but in ASP.NET Core Razor, I had to use `@Html.Raw(((string)ViewData["MyText"]).Replace("\n", "<br />"))`

Comment: I used a slightly different approach, data stored in my case was SQL text: `@Html.Raw(field.Replace("\n", "<br />"))`

Answer (score 4):

The display template is probably the best solution but there is another easy option of using an html helper if you know you're just displaying a string, e.g.:

```
namespace Shaul.Web.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static IHtmlString ReplaceBreaks(this HtmlHelper helper, string str)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(str.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Aggregate((a, b) => a + "<br />" + b));
        }
    }
}
```

And then you'd use it like:

```
@using Shaul.Web.Helpers

@Html.ReplaceBreaks(Model.MultiLineText)
```

Answer (score 3):

You create a display template for your data.
Here's a post detailing how to do it.
[How do I create a MVC Razor template for DisplayFor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710140/how-do-i-create-a-mvc3-razor-template-for-displayfor)

In that template you do the actual translating of newlines into 
 and whatever other work needs to be done for presentation.

Comment: +1 for the template idea but answer credit goes to the actual implementation given by @slapthelownote

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [DisplayTemplates for common DataTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990846/cannot-find-displaytemplates-for-common-datatypes),
I override (introduce?) a default DisplayTemplate for `DataType.MultilineText`, `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MultilineText.cshtml` containing just this line:

```
<span style="white-space: pre-wrap">@this.Model</span>
```

(Of course you could replace this style, by a css-class, or replace newlines inside the view, if you prefer that.)

I guess this template is automatically resolved, because I had no need for `UIHint` or any other reference or registration.

Using the DisplayTemplate instead of introducing a `HtmlHelper`-method has the advantage, that it trickles down to properties and views that are not explicitly defined.
E.g. `DisplayFor(MyClassWithMultilineProperties)` will now also correctly display `MyClassWithMultilineProperties.MyMultilineTextProperty`, if the property was annotated with `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]`.

Comment: The file name must be `MultilineText.cshtml`

Comment: This is the perfect and very clean solution ,without suffering from un-cleaned css or js changes

Answer (score 2):

Try using
`@Html.Raw("<p>" + Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name) + "</p>")`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another extension method option.

```
    public static IHtmlString DisplayFormattedFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, string>> expression)
    {
        string value = Convert.ToString(ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        value = string.Join("<br/>", value.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode));

        return new HtmlString(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with ASP.NET Core 6. The previous answers here did not work with a linq expression in `Html.DisplayFor`. Instead I was constantly getting the `<br/>` tag escaped out in the output HTML.  Trying HtmlString helper methods suggestions did not work.

The following solution was discovered through trial and error.  The `InfoString` had CRLF replaced with the `<br/>` tags as shown in the property code.

**Works**

```
@Html.Raw(@Convert.ToString(item.InfoString))
```

**Did not work**

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InfoString)
```

FYI - my Info String property:

```
public string InfoString
{
   get { return MyInfo.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"<br />"); }
}
```