# How to make a @Html.DisplayFor multiline in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor

I am trying to display a customer address in multiline which works for @Html.EditorFor but not @Html.DisplayFor. I have tried other posts on here but have not got it to work.
Here is what have started with and what I have tried with no luck

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerPostalAddress)
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.CustomerPostalAddress).Replace("\n","<br/>"))
```

Here is the field in the model

```
 [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
 public string CustomerPostalAddress { get; set; }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would want to create a DisplayTemplate in Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/DisplayPostalAddr.cshtml

```
@model string

<p>@Model</p>
```

then give you model a hint on how to display it

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[UIHint("DisplayPostalAddr")]
public string CustomerPostalAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin, I have not yet had the time to try to implement this yet so havent marked it as the answer. I will let you know how I get on

Comment: Tiny typo -should be <p>@Model</p>  I.e. a capital 'M'.  Probably obvious to most, but might fox a newbie.

Comment: Good Catch, @StuartQ. I have edited the answer to reflect what you mentioned.

Comment: The template is used at runtime as advertised. However, to actually display multiple lines, one should use replace <p>@Model<p> with something like <div style="white-space:pre-wrap">@Model</div>, as suggested in the answer by Chtiwi Malek.  Anyway, what's nice about this approach is that it provides a central place to configure the display style, so one need not configure each display separately.

Answer (score 6):

just add this css style property to render multiline texts, this is better then cpu consuming server side strings manipulation like .replace  :

```
.multiline
{
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

then

```
<div class="multiline">
  my multiline
  text
</div>
```

this will render **newlines** like **br** elements.

try it here : https://refork.codicode.com/xaf4

Comment: Unfortunately, this does mean you need to be careful with the whitespace you're using as formatting... it renders that newline between the div and "my multiline" as a newline, too.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [make DisplayFor display line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59249806/422877), I override (introduce?) a default DisplayTemplate for `DataType.MultilineText`, `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MultilineText.cshtml` containing just this line:

```
<span style="white-space: pre-wrap">@this.Model</span>
```

I guess this template is automatically resolved, because I had no need for `UIHint` or any other reference or registration.
(Of course you could also introduce a css-class, or replace newlines inside the view, if you prefer that.)

Using the default DisplayTemplate will fix the line breaks for *all* properties annotated with the (type-safe, meaningful) `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]`, instead of just the ones annotated with `UIHint("DisplayPostalAddr")`.