# Using custom Html helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Trying to use a html helper I found here on the first answer:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030763/how-to-make-html-displayfor-display-line-breaks)

Heres the controller part:

```
 public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayWithBreaksFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        var model = html.Encode(metadata.Model).Replace("\r\n", "<br />\r\n");

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(model);
    }
}
```

and in the view I use:

```
@using HtmlHelpers
```

and

```
@Html.DisplayWithBreaksFor(m => m.MultiLineField)
```

But I am getting an error on both

For the first:

> "The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelpers' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

For the second:

> "'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayWithBreaksFor' and no extension method 'DisplayWithBreaksFor' accepting a first argument of type"
>
> "'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: `HtmlHelpers` is a class name, `@using` expects a namespace. Also, that name clashes with one from the framework.

Comment: Have you used the full path here `@using HtmlHelpers` or just this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the wrong namespace. I think you should not put the method in the controller. Just create a new class. So you can reuse code better. Here is a sample. You can refer. Hope to help, my friend :))

1) I created a new class that have namespace is MvcExam.UtilitiesClass

```
namespace MvcExam.UtilitiesClass
{
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayWithBreaksFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
            var model = html.Encode(metadata.Model).Replace("\r\n", "<br />\r\n");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(model);
        }
    }
}
```

2) In a View

```
@using MvcExam.UtilitiesClass

@Html.DisplayWithBreaksFor(m => m.Name)
```

Comment: @Conor8630: Well played, my friend :))

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the full namespace:

```
@using YourProjectName.YourAssemblyName.FolderNameWhereYourClassLives;
```