# Word Wrap on Displayfor in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, displayfor

I have a Description field that brings back a large amount of text. When it writes to the page it comes out as one big line. I have tried wrapping it in the below two divs

```
         <td>
            <div style="word-wrap:break-word;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </div>
        </td>
```

and

```
         <td>
            <div style="overflow:auto;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </div>
        </td>
```

The strange thing is they both seem to work for a second when the screen first loads and then it goes back to one line.

I have looked online and ever answer I find says the above should work.

Is anyone aware of something I am missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following post may present one or more solutions to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030763/how-to-make-html-displayfor-display-line-breaks/17273367

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table)

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET and everything to do with HTML and CSS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force table cell <td> content to wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6666532/11683)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The links in the comments helped but in the end I had to do a count through the data to add in the br every hundred characters. Then if there where no spaces by the 15th loop it would add one in any way.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString Display100<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        var model = html.Encode(metadata.Model);
                                                  
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;

        if (model.Length > 100)             
        for (int i = 100; i <= model.Length; i++)
        {
                if (model.Length - i > 0)
                {         
                    
                    if (Char.ToString(model[i]) == " ")
                    {
                        model = model.Insert(i, "<br />");
                        i += 100;
                        i = i.Round(100);
                    }
                    if(((double)i/100) % 1 > 0.15)
                    {
                        model = model.Insert(i, "<br />");
                        i += 100;
                        i = i.Round(100);
                    }
                }
        }
```