# Changing Html.DisplayFor boolean checkbox MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a boolean property IsActive. In the view is a list of objects with their properties (including IsActive). But in the list the IsActive is a non-editable checkbox since it's boolean. If I change DisplayFor() to DisplayTextFor() then it will just display True or false instead of checkbox. How can I change True and false to 'Active' and 'Inactive' where Active is true and Inactive is false?

```
      @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
```

And then I would style the 'Active' to green and 'Inactive' to red

Comment: I added a complete example for doing that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710140/how-do-i-create-a-mvc-razor-template-for-displayfor/51821067#51821067.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use a display template to format the way your property is displayed.

Create a `DisplayTemplates` folder either under `~/Shared` or in the View folder where the view that will be using this template exists.

Add a new partial view to this folder. Name it anything you'd like, e.g. `IsActive.cshtml`

```
@model bool
@if (Model == true)
{
    @Html.Encode("Active")
}
@if (Model == false)
{
    @Html.Encode("Inactive")
}
```

Now add data annotation to your property to let it know to use this display template.

```
[UIHint("IsActive")]
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

Use `Html.DisplayFor` on any bool with this annotation and it will be formatted according to the display template with the matching name. With some tweaking, you can place the color change style directly in your display template.

Comment: You also can apply the template with the `templateName` parameter of `Html.DisplayFor`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a old question, but this might help someone. I had the exact same problem and solved with `@(IsFooBar ? "Yes" : "No")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
@if (item.IsActive) 
{ 
    @string.Format("Active");
}
else
{ 
    @string.Format("Inactive");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to complement nightshifted's solution so that it works well with localized string as well. Also, using `@Html.Encode()` strings with special characters are encoded wrong. For example "Kyllä" (Finnish for Yes) gets encoded badly. That is why there is no `@Html.Encode()` at all in my solution.

This solution assumes that you are using localization with SharedResources approach (refer [ASP.NET Core Localization with help of SharedResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647384/asp-net-core-localization-with-help-of-sharedresources))

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@model bool
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResources> L

@if (Model)
{
    @L["Yes"]
}
else
{
    @L["No"]
}
```