# JavaScript if else condition for setting event color on fullcalendar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar (http://fullcalendar.io) to implement a calendar. I have a table in my DB which has the following rows - 
[DB table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dnXc.png)

This is the view that I have -

```
@model IEnumerable<Fit.Models.Events>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Calendar";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Fit</title>
    <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>

    <div id="calendar"></div>
    <div style="display: none">

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartTime)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndTime)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsConfirmed)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="events">
                <td class="title">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td class="start">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartTime)
                </td>
                <td class="end">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td class="confirmed">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.IsConfirmed)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/calendar")
}
```

This is the JavaScript -

```
var events = [];
$(".events").each(function () {
    var title = $(".title", this).text().trim();
    var start = $(".start", this).text().trim();
    var end = $(".end", this).text().trim();
    var allDay = "false";
    var confirmed = $(".confirmed", this).text().trim();
    var colour = "green";
    var textColour = "white";
    if (confirmed == "False") {
        colour = "yellow";
        textColour = "red";
    }

    var event = {
        "title": title,
        "start": start,
        "end": end,
        "allDay": allDay,
        "color": colour,
        "textColor": textColour
    };
    events.push(event);
});

$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    themeSystem: 'jquery-ui',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
    },
    locale: 'au',
    events: events,
    selectable: true,
    selectOverlap: false,
    validRange: function (nowDate) {
        return {
            start: nowDate.subtract(1,'days')
        };       
    },
    handleWindowResize: true,
    height: 450,
    aspectRatio: 0.5,
    displayEventTime: true,
    timeFormat: 'H:mm',

    select: function (start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        var d = new Date(start);
        var d2 = new Date(end);
        var m = new moment(d).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        var m2 = new moment(d2).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        m = encodeURIComponent(m);
        m2 = encodeURIComponent(m2);
        var uri = "/Events/Create?date=" + m + "&date2=" + m2;
        $(location).attr('href', uri);
    }
});
```

The problem is when trying to set the color for the events on the calendar. My intention is to set green and white for events which has IsConfirmed as True and yellow and red for events which has IsConfirmed as False. Right now, both events are showing up in green and white which is not correct as one of the events has IsConfirmed as false.

What am I doing wrong? If I've missed out anything, do let me know!

Comment: running your code in a JSFiddle using the latest Chrome I can't see a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/4/ , it changes the colours the way you want. It does give you a warning about the colour variables being out of scope though. Technically you should declare them once _before_ your if statement, and only use the code within the if to populate them. Then they won't be out of scope when you come to put them in the event. Maybe some JS engines are less tolerant of this, and it's breaking. Have you checked your console for errors about undefined variables or similar?

Comment: BTW putting the events into a table and then parsing the HTML to turn them into fullCalendar events isn't a brilliant approach - it's code-intensive and (comparatively) slow. It would make more sense to use your C#/Razor code to generate some JSON directly from the model data which you can then just inject into the JavaScript when the page loads.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @ADyson. There are no errors on the console. I changed my code to declare them before the if statement as you stated, but it still doesn't work. I am using the latest Chrome as well. Since we know that the logic is right, is there any other way to troubleshoot this? 
Thanks for the tip on JSON! I was taught to do it this this way and it worked, so didn't care too much.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson ! Your JSFiddle gave me a hint and led me to solve the issue. Please take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what was going wrong. The IsConfirmed attribute is a boolean attribute (I should have mentioned this in my original post, my bad. I didn't think it would be relevant). This was the cause of the problem.

To figure out what was going on, I wrote console.log(confirmed) in my Javascript to check whether it is getting a value from my HTML. It was empty. I removed the trailing `.text().trim()` and then checked again. This time the console showed that an object was parsed. So we are able to get an object from parsing the HTML but no text from it.

Then looking at @ADyson 's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/4/) in the comment above, I saw that he was using string values for IsConfirmed. That made me wonder whether the data type of the field was causing some problem.

Viewing the source of my page on the browser, I saw that `@Html.DisplayFor` converts the IsConfirmed attribute to a checkbox for display and not the value. So there was no way to convert a checkbox to text (what I was doing in my JavaScript).

On researching this, I reached [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815344/changing-html-displayfor-boolean-checkbox-mvc).

I changed `@Html.DisplayFor` to `@Html.DisplayTextFor` for IsConfirmed and that solved the problem.

Comment: Well spotted. I hadn't remembered that DisplayFor would do that to a boolean. I just assumed since you were treating it as a string in the JS it must be a string in the C#. My bad for making too many assumptions!